# Jquery change text to URL with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-sites

I'm working with Google Sites right now. I've added an HTML Box to my page and added my script. What the script should do is, that when I click on a text, that this text changes its displaytext and adds an href to it. The text is in a table in a "td" with the class "hey". My first function was this

```
 function showitnow() {
 var div_data = "<br> <br> <a href='https://www.google.com'>Test</a>";
 $(".hey").html(div_data);
}

$(".hey").click(function() {
    showitnow();
});
```

I've copied this function from here. When I click on the field with the class "hey", it only changes my text to "Test". The site knows, that "Test" is a link, but the href went missing, so nothings happens when you click on it. After that I've tried to use the setAttribute and setProperties functions, that were mentioned here on the forum, but they also didn't work. I've noticed, on some versions of Jquery, that when I click on the text, the Firebug console says "Rejecting .setAttribute".

My Question is, are these functions forbidden on Google Sites or is there another way to add a Link and change the display text?

I'm using Version 1.10.1 of Jquery.

Comment: Did you see what error occurs in console log when you click?

Comment: Like I said, if I want to change the attribute, the console says "Rejecting <a> . setAttribute"

Comment: No need to set attribute because already you set in href in div_data. i have place my code as an answer that is working i have tested so use that.

Comment: I know. I meant, that I also tried it that way with setting an attribute

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(".hey").click(function() {
        var div_data = "<br> <br> <a href='https://www.google.com'>Test</a>";

     $(this).append(div_data );
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your code, but it does not work with the ".each()". If I remove the ".each()" - part, the href still remains empty. <a target="_blank">Test</a>

Comment: did u get the solution

Comment: the href of test still remains empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hey").click(function() {
        var div_data = '<br> <br> <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Test</a>';
         $(".hey").html(div_data);
    });
})
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59gWn/)

Comment: href still empty. I forgot to post this error, that occurs "Cannot emulate complex event handler div onsubmit="t" in ES5/3 mode". I googled this error. The only thing I've found was that the Jquery version is important, but I've already tried different versions of Jquery

Comment: i have added jsfiddle demo to my answer its working there. you can see that demo.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want. I've tried your code on Google Sites, but it only changes the displaytext to "Test" and then Firebug says it's like this "<a target="_blank">Test</a>"

Comment: You could try wrapping the html in a `$()` so that it gets treated as a fragment instead of a string? Like so: `$('<br><br><a href="https://www.google.com">Test</a>')`